# what does this problem on ubuntu rvm mean? what do i have to do?

Tags: ruby, rvm

so im trying to install ruby 2.6 on rvm but im getting this problem. I've already reinstalled rvm, but i dont know what to do, im new with this thing...[photo of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQvfH.png)

Comment: it seems to be saying that "md5" isn't installed.  which Operating system are you using? (is this Ubuntu on WSL?)

Comment: yep, ubuntu on wsl (windows 11)

Comment: Looks like you need to install "build essentials" you could try using the instructions from https://rvm.io/rvm/install or https://gist.github.com/sixfeetover/789947

Comment: i've already tried, but this error keeps coming :(

Comment: this particularly is the bit you'll need: `apt-get install build-essential` remember that you'll need to `sudo apt...` or `sudo -s` before to get an elevated shell/command